# React render link containing a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to do the following:

```js
<tbody>
    {projects.map(function(project, i) { return (
    <tr key={i}>
        <td>
            {project.id}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='#/systemlist?projId={project.id}'>{project.name}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    );} )}
</tbody>
```

It should point to another component, using router. It all works, except the {project.id} not being rendered as a value. How to do that? Everything else outside of href  works.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are couple ways how you can solve this issue

1. String concatenation

   ```
   <a href={ '#/systemlist?projId=' + project.id }>{project.name}</a>
   ```
2. [`ES2015 string templates`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

   ```
   <a href={ `#/systemlist?projId=${project.id}` }>{project.name}</a>
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29360/)